# Non-local lambda expression cannot have a capture-default

Tags: c++, lambda

I'm using lambda expressions to reduce else-if blocks when decoding a string into an operation- for instance, "sin" -> std::sin(x). I define a struct in the header file:

```
struct func{
    std::string symbol;
    uint8_t type;

    std::function<double (double, double)> operate;
};
```

Where `symbol` is the string that represents the function, and `type` is the number of inputs the function takes. In the cpp file, I initialize a `func` object as follows:
`func f1{"sin", ONE_INPUT, [=] (double a, double b){return std::sin(a);}};`

But when I compile the cpp file using `g++ calc.cpp -o2 -std=c++17 -o calc.out`, I get an error for the instantiation of each `func` object:
`error: non-local lambda expression cannot have a capture-default`

I've tried searching for this error online, but all I found was [this discussion post](https://github.com/Reconfigurable-Computing-CalPoly-Pomona/Reconfigurable-BLAST-N/issues/1) where the solution says to make sure my g++ is version 7.4 or greater. However, my clang version is 12.0.0, so I doubt this is the issue.

Here is a MRE:

```
#define ONE_INPUT 0
#define TWO_INPUT 1

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>
#include <functional>

struct func{
    std::string symbol;
    uint8_t type;

    std::function<double (double, double)> operate;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    func f1{"sin", ONE_INPUT, [=] (double a, double b){return std::sin(a);}};
    func f2{"cos", ONE_INPUT, [=] (double a, double b){return std::cos(a);}};
    func f3{"tan", ONE_INPUT, [=] (double a, double b){return std::tan(a);}};
}
```

Comment: Remove the `capture-default` from your lambdas. `[]` instead of `[=]`.

Comment: This fixed the problem! Sorry, what does the "capture-default" in lambdas mean and why is it giving me errors?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Comment: Your code does compile in my env.

Comment: You should always try to reproduce the error with the code you are going to post on SO. I guess in your original code, the declaration of `f1`, `f2` and `f3` are global, hence the error you get. By putting them inside `main`, you change the behavior and made your error not reproducible.